# How to find maximum and minimum file size along with their path in a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to find out the maximum, minimum and average file size along with their path. Incase a directory holds similar file sile (say 15kb,15kb) it should display the path of both files and its files size as once. without useing `head` and `tail` command can we generate the output.(if we use `tail -n 2` it will produce last two lines, instead do we have any other alternative to do that. For instance,a directory holds 20 files of same size(say file1--10b ,file2--10b......file20--10b) instead of using `tail -n 20`command do we have any command that takes automatically those 20 files of same size.

My code :

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "please pass arguments" 
exit
fi

if [ -d $dir ]
then
    if [ -z "$(ls -1A -- $dir)" ]
      then
        echo " directory exists but its empty" 
        else
                printf "minimum file size: %s\n" 
                du $dir -hab | sort -n -r |tail -n 2
                 find "$dir" -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -n -r | head -n 1 | {
                read -r size name
                printf "maximum file size: %d\n\t%s\n" "$size" "$name"
                }

                printf "average file size: %s"
                du $dir -sk | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s/NR}'
    fi
        else
        echo " directory doesn't exists"
fi
```

my output is: $`./filestats testdir`

```
minimum file size:  
15  testdir/subdir3/subdir4/file3.txt
15  testdir/subdir1/file5.txt
maximum file size: 48
    testdir/file7.txt
average file size: 60
```

the actual output should be as follows:
   `$`./filestats testdir

```
minimum file size: 15 
        testdir/subdir3/subdir4/file3.txt
        testdir/subdir1/file5.txt
    maximum file size: 48
        testdir/file7.txt
        testdir/file8.txt
    average file size: 60
```

Comment: You can take a look here - https://superuser.com/questions/228853/how-to-find-the-largest-file-in-a-directory for reference.

Answer (score 4):

On a GNU system:

```
#! /bin/sh -
find "$1" -type f -printf '%s\0  %p\n\0' |
  awk -vRS='\0' '
    {getline file}
    {n++; sum += $0; files[$0] = files[$0] file}
    $0 < min || n == 1 {min = $0}
    $0 > max || n == 1 {max = $0}
    END {
      if (n)
        printf "min: %d\n%s\nmax: %d\n%s\naverage: %.17g\n", \
          min, files[min], max, files[max], sum/n
    }'
```

That's for file size (here *regular* files only with `-type f`), as opposed to disk usage. For disk usage, use `%k` or `%b` instead of `%s` in the argument to `find`'s `-printf`.

That assumes `$1` does not look like a `find` option or predicate (like `-L`, `!`, `(`, `-name`...).

```
$ that-script /usr/bin
min: 30
  /usr/bin/rgrep
  /usr/bin/xlinks2

max: 11634832
  /usr/bin/doxygen

average: 170653.62570735652
```

Comment: The code which you had posted is throwing an error. The message is: `min: 15  max: 15 avg: 15`. I will edit my code once again please have a look.

Comment: @buddhasreekanth, I've added an example in the answer. Please try and copy-paste the code as-is and try again.

Comment: I am facing the same problem again. There is no change in the output getting same error again and again as I mentioned in earlier comment. Could you please check my edited code and actual output what I've posted.

Comment: Works fine here. Post your output on https://gist.github.com/ and refer to the link in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I often find shell scripts somewhat clunky, so I wrote a Python script to do it:

```
import os
import sys

dir = "."
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  dir=sys.argv[1]

files = [os.path.join(f[0], x) for f in os.walk(dir) for x in f[2]]
filesWithSizes = [(f, os.stat(f).st_size) for f in files if os.path.exists(f)]

sizes = [f[1] for f in filesWithSizes]
maxSize = max(sizes)
minSize = min(sizes)
avgSize = 0
if len(sizes) > 0:
  avgSize = sum(sizes) / len(sizes)

maxFiles = [f[0] for f in filesWithSizes if f[1] == maxSize]
minFiles = [f[0] for f in filesWithSizes if f[1] == minSize]

print("Minimum file size: {}".format(minSize))
for f in minFiles:
  print("  " + f)
print("Maximum file size: {}".format(maxSize))
for f in maxFiles:
  print("  " + f)
print("Average file size: {}".format(avgSize))
```