# How to find files with the smallest size in a directory

Tags: shell-script

I need to find all files of the smallest size in a directory.

My code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$1"
   printf "minimum file size: %s\n"
            du $dir -hab | sort -n -r |tail
```

This code displays the smallest files but I need the least small file sizes should be display automatically.

My output:

```
file size:
15  testdir/subdir3/subdir4/file3.txt
15  testdir/subdir1/file5.txt
```

Actual output should display like:

```
file size: 15
        testdir/subdir3/subdir4/file3.txt
        testdir/subdir1/file5.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by _least_? Are you looking for the smallest file in a directory or all files that share the smallest size? Please [edit] your question and include a specific example so we can understand.

Comment: @Terdon Im looking for the all files that have smallest size in a directory. for example having same size for all 10 files(1. xxx.txt -4kb , 2.yyy.txt -4kb.........10. zzz.txt -4kb) in a directory

Comment: Maybe instead of posting many variations on your original question, you could clarify why the [answers you got on your original question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200323) are not satisfactory.

Comment: Your code had it almost right -- just add ``-n 1`` to tail. It's actually slightly more optimal to `sort -n | head -1`, especially if the du output is very large.

Comment: @Otheus if I add -n 1 to tail it shows only one smallest file size but I want all the smallest file size in a directory. For example,  a directory comprises of 10 smallest file size (1. xxx.txt -4kb , 2.yyy.txt -4kb.........10. zzz.txt -4kb) in a directory. It  should display all files having small and same file size.

Comment: @Otheus, his original question was clearer and [the answers he got there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200323) did that AFAICT.

Comment: Indeed. @StéphaneChazelas I had seen your answer, but I misread your code! :) Maybe after 1 week he forgot?  Buddha, please go back to Stephane's answer and <<accept>> it.

Comment: @Otheus If I  accept Stephane Chazelas answer I have to change my enitre code and need to write a new code from scratch. Could you please read my question once,I edited it.

Comment: Buddha, thanks for rewording. Stephane's code does precisely what you ask (it does a little more too, but you can remove that and output only the part you need).

Comment: @Otheus stephane code is working but it works for disk space. I tried with `find` and `du` command to generate output for smallest file size but its showing only one path instead of multiple files with same file size.  I am confused which command I have to use. Could you please tell me difference between `du` and `find` command.

Comment: The ``du`` and ``find .. -printf %b`` will print out the disk _usage_ of the file -- how many bytes of the disk are consumed -- while ``find .. -printf %s`` is outputting the file's ``size``. In most filesystems (there are exceptions) files are allocate only by blocks. If a file's _size_ is 1 byte, it still requires at least 1 block and therefore ``1*BLOCK_SIZE`` bytes of _usage_. If its size is 511 bytes,  it still uses only 512 bytes of _usage_. So it's just a matter of using  ``%s`` or ``%b`` depending on what you want

Comment: @Otheus In `printf` command do we have any parameter to show path of file size. In my code `find "$dir" -printf "%s %p\n%s" | sort -n | tail -1 | {
                read -r size name
                printf "maximum file size: %s\n\t%s\n" "$size" "$name"
                }` .It showing path only upto the directory not looking for files. For example:  `$ /home/sreekanth/testdir/subdir1` this was the error Im facing. could you please let me know.

Comment: `-printf "%s %p\n%s"` is wrong. Should be only `-printf "%s %p\n"` See the difference and why it screwed up your pipeline?

Comment: @otheus I'm sorry. Its correct what you have said.  '-printf "%s %p\n` showing path only upto the directory not looking for files. my code is ` find "$dir" -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | { read -r size name printf "maximum file size: %s\n\t%s\n" "$size" "$name" } `. This code gives me only maximum directory size not the file size but i need only maximum file size.

Comment: @otheus One more question is how to get the multiple same file size in a directory. my code is ` find "$dir"  -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n -r | tail -n 1 | { read -r size name
                printf "minimum file size: %d\n\t%s\n" "$size" "$name"
                }`

Comment: I'm not helping you more, Buddha. @StéphaneChazelas perfectly answered your question already.

Comment: @Otheus But the Stephane's code is not working anymore in my system.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps like this:

```bash
find /some/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' | \
    sort -n | \
    awk '
        NR == 1 { s = $1 }
        $1 != s { exit }
        1'
```

(assuming GNU `find(1)`).

**Edit:** How the `awk` part works:

- `awk` receives a list of lines `<size><tab><filename>`, sorted by `<size>`; the smallest files are thus grouped at the beginning of the list
- `NR == 1` applies only to the first line; it initializes `s` to the common size of the smallest files
- `$1 != s` applies when we find a file with a size bigger than `s`; since the list is sorted by size, all subsequent files are at least as big, so we can bail out
- if we got to `1`, the rule `$1 != s` didn't match, so the file has exactly size `s`; `1` is equivalent to `{ print }`, so we print it.

Comment: Hope you don't mind. The l/L was hard to distinguish from ``1`` and I think the last ``1`` should have been to output the filename. Also maxdepth should come first to avoid the dreaded gnu warning. Oh, and ``\t`` to `` ``

Comment: @Otheus: Your edit breaks if any of the filenames contain spaces.  Thus, sorry, but no.  I replaced `l` by `s` though.

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I don't get the purpose of "1" on the last line. That outputs the file size *and* the filename. OP wanted just the *filename*. Still, swap maxdepth/type

Comment: @Otheus: No, the OP wanted the filenames.  There is no need for this dance if he just wanted the size, he could just replace `tail` by `tail -1` in his initial command.  And BTW, in order to keep just the filenames from my command above it's enough to pipe the results through `cut -f 2-`.  That's the point of using a tab as separator in the `-printf` clause.

Comment: He wanted the filenames and originally in my comment I wrote ``size`` and then edited it. So the last line should be ``{ print $2 }``. Why another pipe?

Comment: Oh and there's the discussion on his main post where he wants all the files, not just the only matching one that would have been solved with ``tail -1``. BTW: Look at Stephane's awk code. It's a thing of beauty. Not taking anything away from yours.

Comment: @Otheus: _Why another pipe?_ - Because the filename might contain either spaces or tabs? That too can be done with `awk(1)`, but it isn't worth the pain, it's what `cut(1)` does best.

Comment: OK, I see your point now. So ``cut -f 2-`` ?

Comment: @Icd047 could you please explain the part of `awk` code.

Comment: @buddha sreekanth: Added.

Answer (score 0):

`SMALLEST_FILE=$(ls -SrqL $dir | head -1)`